# MYSQL Search function and facebook share

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, search

I have two hurdles that i am struggling to get past.

1) I want to have a search function that will search the name and last name of the MYSQL database.

2)Here is an example of the page [Sample link](http://ourdevspot.com/step/1/final/index2.php) ( code shown below )when a user clicks on the badge i want a funcion that the user can share his/her badge on facebook. Same applies when the user search for his/her name.

I have searched and researched a lot but cannot seem to get it to work. I am not an expert so i turn to you the masters of Stackoverflow.

```
<div id="id_display">
<?php
require "configflag.php"; // database connection is here

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MY_DATABASE");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$name = $rows['name'];
$last_name = $rows['last_name'];
$state = $rows['state'];
$email = $rows['email'];

echo '<div id="display">';
echo "$name<br>$last_name<br><br>$state";
echo '</div>';

echo '<ul class="lineone">';
echo '<li class="linetwo"><br></li>';
echo "</ul>";
echo '<ul class="lineone">';
echo '<li class="linetwo"><br></li>';
echo "</ul>";
}
?>
</div><!--end id display-->
```

Comment: We are here to HELP with programming problems. We are not here to do your job for you, nor just bang out code for you because you can't/won't do it yourself. YOU write some code, and we'll maybe try help fix it.

Comment: I'll help you with this.  They don't exactly make Facebook Open Graph easy, even if you read everything about it.  Gimme about 10 minutes, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not expecting you to do my work and bang out code just some guidelines that's all. I have done the code but keep getting errors. You can look at my previous questions nobody BANGED me code just gave guidelines and i did the code. No need to be rude because you have experience and i don't have.

Comment: @durbnpoisn thank you for the help. I have read up on Facebook Open Graph and it seriously hectic especially for my skills level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is generate a dynamic SHARE tag on your page.  This will serve as an example for how to do it.  Took me a while to figure this out too.  There are some answers here on SO, but everything is so specific to certain situations, there is no clear method.  But I think this this will help.
I used this myself on [this page](http://dpoisn.com/surveys/?surveyId=3)

Post these tags inside the HEAD of your page.  You must pass the parameters in from your share button:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://dpoisn.com/surveys/images/surveyFBShare.png"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://dpoisn.com/surveys/?result=<? echo $_GET['result'] ?>&surveyId=<? echo $_GET['surveyId']?>&quizName=<? echo $_GET['quizName'] ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="DPoisn Quiz Page - <? echo $_GET['quizName'] ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="I scored <? echo $_GET['result'] .'%' ?>  Try it yourself!" />
```

Once that's in there, Facebook's Open Graph will know what to do with the Share.  For that code, you need this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://dpoisn.com/surveys/?result=<? echo $perc .'%' ?>%', 'Fb Share', 'You have scored <? echo $perc .'%' ?>', 'http://dpoisn.com/surveys/images/surveyFBShare.png', 520, 350)"><img src="images/fbShareButton.png" alt="fbShare" border="0"></a>
        <script>
        function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
            var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
            var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
            window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fdpoisn.com%2Fsurveys%2F%3Fresult%3D<? echo $perc ?>%26surveyId%3D<? echo $whichSurvey ?>%26quizName%3D<? echo $surveyName ?>',toolbar=0,status=0,width=400, height=300);

        }
        </script>
```

Now...  You're going to have to totally repurpose this for you own needs.  But that is the basic idea.  To recap:

1. Get your og: meta tags set
2. Get the FB share button link, with the javascript to create the popup.
3. After you look over this, do a Google search for Facebook Open Graph.  It will explain in better detail what is going on here.

Comment: This is awesome thank you. This has been one hectic headache. This gives me at least some direction. Cant thank you enough.

Comment: For what it's worth, it took me MANY MANY hours of frustration to figure this out.  And I too leaned on answers from SO before I finally figured it out.  In my case, it was even more complex because the link I'm SHARING is generated from a different page than where the link goes.  So the tags are on one page, and the share is on another.  But, in the end, it works.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for months. Its going to be tricky to implement and adapt for my purpose but i have the framework and that's a BIG start. Thank you thank you